# possible bug in reviewing reopen votes?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I just reviewed [Status of Beal, Granville, Tijdeman-Zagier Conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28764/status-of-beal-granville-tijdeman-zagier-conjecture) which had a vote to re-open, and tried to select "keep closed". But then I got a pop-up asking me to confirm that I wanted to re-open the question...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, this is a [known bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184603/clicking-leave-closed-shows-the-reopen-pop-up)

Answer (score 2):

[This has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186188/178438), you may need to wait a few hours for the new build.

> Oops, this was caused by a javascript copy-paste gone awry. It's fixed now – sorry about that.